# How to generalize html pages common parts in MVC Spring application

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC web application, it only uses html pages, my first problem was to generalize the header, footer, and side-menu in all html pages, so that they come from one source in all pages ,I used the jquery.load method  to simulate the include directive of the jsp pages, but this way, I had to add the load code in all pages, I want you to help me implementing another approach, where I always return a template page that has the header, footer and side menu, but load the content dynamically based on the originally user requested page, can u give me any idea on how to implement this in a Spring MVC application where only html pages are allowed.

Comment: Google for example apache tiles, thymeleaf.

Comment: Sitemesh is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring MVC with Thymeleaf would be your best pick. This [article](https://spring.io/blog/2012/10/30/spring-mvc-from-jsp-and-tiles-to-thymeleaf) would be a great start

It offers you a way to design your layout files analogues to the example given, while still being in a realm of plain HTML files

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head th:include="thymeleaf/layout :: headerFragment">
 <!-- replaced with fragment content -->
 <!—- 'thymeleaf/layout' refers to /thymeleaf/layout.html on the filesystem -->
 </head>

 <body>

 <div th:include="thymeleaf/layout :: menuFragment">
 </div>
 <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(users)}">
 <table>
   …
   <tbody>
     <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
      <td th:text="${user.firstName}">John</td>
      <td th:text="${user.lastName}">Smith</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

a quote from the blog

> Thymeleaf defines itself as an  XML / XHTML / HTML5 template engine.
>
> It is not based on JSPs but rather on some plain HTML files with a
>   little bit of namespace magic.